# One one image uploading with different postkeys but i want to store all images under one postkey in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[One one image uploading with different postkeys but i want to store all images under one postkey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhWsd.png)

This is the code where im uploading all the images to firebase storage and databse with post key but one one images are storing with different post key and i want to store all the uploaded images into one post key under blog in firebase databse. Please help me _This is th issue im facing from past few days and i want to retrieve all the uploaded images under one postkey

```
 upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            UploadTask uploadTask;
            if( selectedImageGridView.getChildCount()!= 0)
            {
                for ( int i = 0; i < selectedImages.size(); i++) {
                    blogimages   =  new ArrayList<>();
                   Uri  uri = Uri.parse("file://"+selectedImages.get(i));
                    final String CurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    StorageReference reference = mstorageReference.child("Blog_pics/users").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
                    uploadTask = reference.putFile(uri);

                   uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            final Uri downloaduri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            Log.v("DOWNLOAD URI", String.valueOf(downloaduri));
                            blogimages.add(downloaduri.toString());
                            Log.v("BLOGGIMAGES", String.valueOf(blogimages));
                            final String key = mdatabaseReference.push().getKey();
                            final String posttitle = desc.getText().toString();
                            final String CurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            int l = 0;
                            while (l < blogimages.size()){
                             Log.v("BLOGIMAGESSIZE", String.valueOf(blogimages.size()));
                                Map n = new HashMap();
                                int countingImage = 0;
                                n.put(String.valueOf("img" + countingImage), blogimages.get(l).toString());
                                Log.v("MapCount", String.valueOf(n));
                                mdatabaseReference.child(key).child("images").updateChildren(n).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(PhotoUploadActivity.this, "got download url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        } else{

                                            Toast.makeText(PhotoUploadActivity.this, "Failed to put in db", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                l++;
                                countingImage++;
                            }
                            }

                    }) .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the database structure that you expect to achieve? Please edit your question and add the expected schema.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this line

```
StorageReference reference = mstorageReference.child("Blog_pics/users").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

to this lines: you have to put those lines **befor**  the for loop

```
String userId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    StorageReference reference = mstorageReference.child("Blog_pics/users").child(userId);
```

then  **inside** the loop

```
refrence.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = reference.putFile(uri);
...
```

Comment: for loop is upto images storing  to firebase. if i'm passing push function only one  image url is storing and storing without push then its storing all the image urls in firebase database